# Official "Xbox Live API" - Where to find knowledgable people?

Tags: xbox-live

I havent seen many posts here regarding the xbox live api offered by Microsoft.  Can anyone point me a a site where there is an active xbox live api community?

Answer (score 10):

This is rather vague so I will provide a broad answer.

**ID@Xbox**

If you're an independent publisher looking to implement Xbox Live Services into your game sign-up with ID@Xbox (https://www.xbox.com/en-US/developers/id). There you will be given access to developer forums and thorough documentation. Official and full of knowledgeable people.

**Creators Program**

If you're creating an app for the Xbox One marketplace or Windows 10 you can join the Xbox Live Creators Program (https://www.xbox.com/developers/creators-program). This is much more streamlined than ID@Xbox and has less verification steps. It's a quick way to integrate Xbox Live with whatever you are doing.

**Documentation**

For complete documentation on the Xbox Live API visit (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/xbox-live/) which is assuming you already have the necessary access through either ID@Xbox or the Creators Program.

The aforementioned avenues are the official way to tap in and join the community.

**Other Options**

Above all else, if you're simply looking to integrate Xbox Live into your website or something simple - Microsoft isn't interested. There is no official support for that unless you're one of the above partners. However - there remain options.

1) OpenXBL (https://xbl.io) offers up support for Xbox Live API calls and sign-in authentication. Plenty of demo projects to get you going. There is also a Discord channel available to chat with others using the service.

2) https://xboxapi.com also offers up support for Xbox Live API calls.

Comment: If I want to create some plugin for other apps/games, how can I do this? Which link is relevant for this?